# Dynamic nested Views in Android don't restore Layout correctly after Rotation

Tags: android, nested, android-viewpager, fragment, android-framelayout

I created an MasterDetailFlow Fragment inside an Tab-Viewpager.
You can find the sourcecode here:
https://github.com/M1cha/android_MasterDetailFlow_with_tabs

Basically the Fragment inside the ViewPager loads an layout via Inflater and dynamically adds an nested fragment into it.

The layout contains a (static) FrameLayout where another fragment will be be inserted after an ListItem is clicked. The problem is that this FrameLayout is not visible after rotating the screen. I just can see the dynamically inserted ListFragment.

any ideas?